# WPF c# onStartUp() view model problem with multiple data inputs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observable, ienumerable

Hey all I have the following OnStartup for my **WPF desktop app** that goes to a local directory and gathers all the images within that folder (**box1** being the example code below):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // set the update interval
        var imageSource = new ImageSource(Path.Combine(@"C:\photos\boxes\", "box1"), TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(imageSource);

        var window = new MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = viewModel
        };

        window.Closed += (s, a) => { viewModel.Dispose(); };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

This works just fine for the component I have on the **MainWindow.xaml** that's label **box1** but the other boxes 2-9 do not load their own images from their respective folders - they all show the same images as box1 has.

The **structure of the directory** is this:

```
 C:\
  |-photos\
     |boxes\
       |box1
       |box2
       |box3
       |box4
       |box5
       |box6
       |box7
       |box8
       |box9
       |box10
```

On the **MainWindow** I have this code that allows all those photos from each directory into its own element:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <!-- List of supported animations -->
    <FluidKit:SlideTransition x:Key="SlideTransition" x:Shared="False"/>
    <FluidKit:CubeTransition x:Key="CubeTransition" Rotation="BottomToTop" x:Shared="False"/>
    <FluidKit:FlipTransition x:Key="FlipTransition" x:Shared="False"/>
    <local:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter"/>
    <!-- Data template for animations -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:Shared="False">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"
               Stretch="Fill"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <FluidKit:TransitionPresenter RestDuration="0:0:3" 
                                      IsLooped="True" 
                                    Transition="{StaticResource FlipTransition}" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding box1}" 
                                         Width="357" 
                                        Height="272" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
                                        x:Name="box1" 
                                        Margin="0,0,0,454"/>
    <FluidKit:TransitionPresenter RestDuration="0:0:3" 
                                      IsLooped="True" 
                                    Transition="{StaticResource FlipTransition}" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding box2}" 
                                         Width="357" 
                                        Height="272" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
                                        x:Name="box2" 
                                        Margin="357,0,0,0"/>
   ETC.......
```

Like I said above, this first element `ItemsSource="{Binding box1}"` loads the images as they should be from the **box1 directory** just fine but all the other **2-9** after that are **loaded the same images as box1.**

The **mainWindowViewModel** code looks like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _token1;
    private readonly IDisposable _token2;
    ...ETC

    public MainWindowViewModel(IImageSource imageSource)
    {
        // subscribe to update images at regular intervals
        _token1 = imageSource
            .GetImages().ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
            .Subscribe(i => UpdateImages(i, box1), ex => ShowError(ex));

        _token2 = imageSource
            .GetImages().ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
            .Subscribe(i => UpdateImages(i, box2), ex => ShowError(ex));
        ETC...
    }

    private void ShowError(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Photo Gallery", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the animation's images.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="images">The images to update with</param>
    /// <param name="animation">The animation to update</param>
    private void UpdateImages(IEnumerable<string> images, ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> animation)
    {
        animation.Clear();

        foreach (var i in images)
        {
            animation.Add(new ImageViewModel { Path = i });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of images used for the first animation. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> box1 { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> box2 { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();

    ETC...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _token1.Dispose();
        _token2.Dispose();
        ETC...
    }
}
```

The function that loops to get each file image within the directory is this:

```
public class ImageSource : IImageSource
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly TimeSpan _interval;

    public ImageSource(string path, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        _path = path;
        _interval = interval;
    }

    public IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> GetImages()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
        {
            return Observable.Empty<IEnumerable<string>>();
        }

        return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<string>>(observer =>
        {
            return TaskPoolScheduler.Default.ScheduleAsync(async (ctrl, ct) =>
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        var images = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.jpg");

                        // Don’t do anything unless there are a minimum of 10 images.
                        if (images.Count() > 9)
                        {
                            observer.OnNext(images.PickRandom());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        observer.OnError(ex);
                        throw;
                    }

                    await ctrl.Sleep(_interval).ConfigureAwait(false);
                 }
            });
        });
    }
```

The code currently goes to each of the `ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> box[X] { get; set; }` and sets the path to each image within that folder. **Box2-10** are the **same files as box 1** of course.

How can I modify that `onStartup()` code to allow for it to consume each box folders' files and place them into the appropriate box # component instead of just using that box1 files?

Thanks!

**UPDATE #1**

Looks like I have 2 errors for the MainWindowViewModel.cs

[image]

> Error  CS0535  'MainWindowViewModel' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'

[image]

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PhotoGallery.ImageSource>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<PhotoGallery.IImageSource>'

Comment: cudos for showing me a new way to align attributes in xaml.

Comment: about your errors: I wrote everything in browser in answer box without Intellisense and compiler. fixes are simple: 1. implement IDisposable properly - dispose BoxViewModels from Boxes collection. 2. change constructor to accept necessary type: `public MainWindowViewModel(Ilist<ImageSource> imageSources)` or change inialization: `.Select(...).Cast<IImageSource>().ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need one more level in data structure hierarchy: BoxViewModel

```
public class BoxViewModel : IDisposable
{
   private IDisposable _token;

   public void Dispose() { /* dispose _token */}

   public BoxViewModel (IImageSource imageSource)
   {
       // init _token, load Images
   }

   public ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> Images { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();
}
```

MainWindowViewModel is simplified: no tokens, no images loading, only collection of BoxViewModels:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IDisposable
{

    public MainWindowViewModel(Ilist<IImageSource> imageSources)
    {
         var boxes = imageSources.Select(x => new BoxViewModel(x));
         Boxes = new ObservableCollection<BoxViewModel>(boxes);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BoxViewModel> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

init MainWindowViewModel with list:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // set the update interval
    var imageSources = Enumerale.Range(1,9)
                                .Select(n => new ImageSource(Path.Combine(@"C:\photos\boxes\", "box"+n.ToString()), TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
                                .ToList();
    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(imageSources);

    var window = new MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel
    };
    ...
}
```

and use ItemsControl in the View:

```
<Grid>
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <FluidKit:TransitionPresenter RestDuration="0:0:3" 
                                      IsLooped="True" 
                                    Transition="{StaticResource FlipTransition}" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" 
                                         Width="357" 
                                        Height="272" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ASh. I implemented those changes and it looks like I have 2 errors now. Please see the OP update for screen shots and error description.

Comment: And looking at your last bit of XAML code there it seems you put everything in one component? Each of those boxes' components (FluidKit) needs to have different width/heights and positions (margins) on the window. One component can not be used for all 10 box images due to these 3 things.

Comment: @StealthRT, ItemsControl will create 1 TransitionPresenter for each item (boxViewModel) and stack them vertically, because it uses StackPanel to arrange items. If you need a different arrangement, change ItemsPanel, e.g. use UniformGrid: `<ItemsControl><ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/></ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsPanel>`.

Comment: nailing elements to fixed position can be done in Canvas, but WPF allows to  aims to produce adaptive layouts.

Comment: Hum.. Mind showing an example of that?

Comment: example of what? add `<ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/></ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsPanel>` to ItemsControl and you will see 3x3 matrix layout